# Excel - Delimiting addresses creates formulas -don't want

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007, calculated-field, csv

Surely I can't be the only person who's ever have this issue.

I have a dataset which includes many hundreds of addresses in unmanagable formats, but I need to be able to sort them, so [Street Name] [Street Number] is the logical format.

My current method is to delimit then concatenate large sections at a time (some situations require more attention than others, especially where multiple street names are concerned).
However, here's what happens when I delimit this range:

[image: this range]

I tried preformatting some of the target cells to General, Text, Number, but nothing works for the whole set. Sometimes it turns it into a date, sometimes it automatically calculates division and subtraction, sometimes it does actually put it as text, but then of course I can't sort it because it's not a number.

Is there a way to avoid this from happening?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

No you aren't the only person facing this issue, and there are quite a few solutions available in the internet.

However they all turn out to be a bit complex and it's much simpler to understand if the same is done in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba). Nevertheless, it's still doable by [excel-formula](/questions/tagged/excel-formula). So here's my take.

To get the result as below

[image]

you may use these formulas:

```
Cell B2: =IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",A2)),A2,LEFT(A2,(FIND(" ",A2,1)-1)))
Cell C2: =MID(A2,LEN(B2)+2,LEN(A2)-LEN(B2)-LEN(D2)-1)
Cell D2: =IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",A2)),A2,MID(A2,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","~",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","")))),300))
```

and then simply copy & paste to applicable rows below.

**Note:** this formula assumes the character `~` is not being used in the data set. If that isn't the case, replace that character in the formula, with the one that can't be found in the entire data set.

Comment: @Alex if it resolves the issue, accept the answer. if you are still having problem, feel free to discuss it